# Android. How to stop all listeners in a activity after it is paused or finished?(Without listener Reference)

Tags: android

how to stop all listeners in a activity without storing the reference of the listener when the activity is paused or stopped.

I have a listener like this

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("xxx");
        ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
});
```

I have many listeners like this. I dont want to store their refernce to stop them like this.

```
listenerRefernce =   ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    });

ref.removeEventListener(listenerReference)
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think Firebase has a method like getAllListeners that you can use to remove all listeners from a DatabaseReference object. You have to keep reference of the listeners

Answer (score 0):

As [the Firebase documentation says](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query), there is no way to remove a listener without reference on it. So you have to keep all the references.